# How to clear cached struct descriptor and load it again when creating a struct

Tags: oracle, jdbc, weblogic12c, ojdbc

With oracle 12c now oracle.sql.StructDescriptor class is deprecated.
Now you can directly create a struct and bind it to the statement as below.

```
PreparedStatement ps= conn.prepareStatement("text_of_prepared_statement");
Struct mySTRUCT = conn.createStruct (...);
ps.setObject(1, mySTRUCT, Types.STRUCT);
```

The problem is if we change attribute structure of the underlying oracle record type associated with this struct (Ex: Add a new attribute, remove an attribute, change the order of attributes), 
the struct descriptor cached in the JDBC becomes stale.
So the execution will end up with SQLException.
This is also mentioned in the oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/Oracle-object-types.html#GUID-962C3E5C-1208-4A63-8130-6347ED9231C5).

What I need is a way to reload the struct descriptor if it has become stale without using the deprecated oracle.sql.StructDescriptor class or resetting the connection pool.

What I found so far :
We can make use of Weblogic DataSource property "Remove Infected Connections Enabled" to discard the physical connection as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24376/phys_conr.htm#JDBCP1037).

Configurations:
Weblogic 12c
ojdbc7
jdk 1.8

Answer (score 0):

You may call the following to remove the descriptor from cache.

((oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection) conn).removeDescriptor("SQL_type_name");

Comment: Hi Krishna, Thanks for the reply. I've tried this out and this also doesn't work. The other thing is are we allowed to use these internal interfaces/classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
((oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection) conn).removeAllDescriptor();
```

You can use this to remove all types of descriptors from connection before returing to connection pool